# Is it easy to replace range gas stove with cooktop gas stove?

Tags: cabinets, granite, cooktops

I Have a gas range stove which has a built-in oven. I can slide it in and out of the cabinet area. If I remove the gas range there is a 30" width gap on the rear I have drywall and other two sides I have kitchen cabinets with granite countertops.

I would like to change the gas range stove to a cooktop gas stove. any suggestion on how to do this job? Should I change the complete granite top and replace it with a new one or is there any alternative where I don't need to change the entire countertop?

Comment: Do you dislike the current granite? As noted, it's pretty easy to find a new cooktop that will suit your width, but it's tricky to get a strip of countertop in front of the unit that looks good and is solid.

Comment: I like the countertop no issues with it and I don't want to change it too. so I am looking for alternate options to install cooktop

Comment: Will you have a separate oven underneath or just cabinets underneath?

Comment: I will have a cabinet with drawers under the cooktop. At present i have a gas range with oven and i want to get rid of it

Comment: How are you going to make frozen pizza, bake a chicken, or broil some pork chops? "I would like to change the gas range stove to a cooktop gas stove." - why? (going electric is silly, but that'd at least make sense. But not having an oven in the house will lower its resale - or at least at some point someone's going to go, *wait there's no oven*?). Answer to the title is **No**. You either change the counter top and replace it with a new one or you go buy a 30" stove that you like the burners of. You'd have to custom build or source one of your original cabinets; not fun.

Answer (score 1):

Cook top stoves come in many different sizes. Take your measurements and start hunting for one that fits your area. You can get top trim that will cover a gap between the countertop and stove if needed. You shouldn't have to replace your existing countertop. When you find one that fits, make sure they will install it for you because gas line connections are usually not allowed to be done by DIYers.

Comment: I have an existing gas connection. So i don't need to change anything on the gas line.

Comment: Making the connection between the pipe coming out of the wall and the stove/cook top itself, @sagarravula, can be a bit hairy. Many locales will not allow you to make that connection unless you're licensed. Check your local regulations. If you _are_ allowed, be sure to read up on tips for checking for leaks before you turn the gas on - gas leaks tend to lead to Big Boom™. A thing you do _not_ want.

Comment: Thank you for cautioning. I will check with a licensed contractor when working on the gas line.

Comment: @JACK I landed here while researching a similar project. I'm trying to determine if it's possible - a free standing gas range (current) breaks the continuity of the countertop compared to a cooktop which goes in a precise hole. how would that work?

Comment: @LVS  You should ask this in a new question.

Comment: Hooking up a gas appliance to existing gas lines does not require any special expertise, credentialed professionals, or anything but a tad of common sense. It is done thousands of times every day by near-minimum-wage "appliance installers" without issue.

Comment: @kreemoweet  It depends on the location. There are counties/cities that do not allow DIYers  to mess with gas lines.  They have warnings on the gas bills  and on the new appliances  saying it's illegal to do so.

Answer (score -1):

It's easy for a pro.

Amateurs should not consider modifying gas connections. Theoretically it's straightforward, but the consequences of making a mistake are unacceptable.

Comment: Valid points, however this should be a comment as it's not an answer...

Comment: 1) Disagree, since it is a direct answer to the title's question: "Depends on whether you mean easy for you to do or get done." 2) If I comment, people sometimes tell me it should be an answer. If I answer, people sometimes tell me it should be a comment. I've given up trying to read minds and will just put it where I think it belongs. If you don't like it feel free to flag it, downvote it, or -- more usefully -- post a better answer.

Comment: Easy for them is going to the store and getting a new 30" stove. Easy for me is up-charging them for w/e the counter top guys charge.

Comment: Nothing was mentioned in the question about "modifying gas connections". Swapping gas appliances at an established outlet is usually as simple a DIY job as it gets. The "appliance installers" who install new appliances by the thousands every day have no special training or knowledge above that of your typical interested DIY'er.

Comment: We agree that we respectfully disagree.